# how can I use string variable in system("say string variable")?

Tags: c++, system-calls

/* I thought of doing in this way, but it invalid.
 so any help will be appreciated. */

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string name = "Karma";
   string greet = "How was your day?";
   string sums = name + greet;

   system("say %s", sums) // not working
   // system("say sums")  not working

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system(("say " + sums).c_str());`

Comment: Also "[Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)".

Comment: `system` takes a pointer to constant character string not `class string`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I think it has something to do with overloading functions or library confusion and many of our friends here on Stackoverflow consider it lazy coding.  The non- "using namespace... " way of doing it is for every cout or cin is to write it std::cout or std::cin.

Comment: @Eryn I know, it wasn't a question. :) It's a title of the question I wanted to show the OP.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat lol.  Oops!  Thanks for letting me know.  Guess I didn't realize that it was a link!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
system(("say" + sums).c_str())
```

Instead of:

```
system("say %s", sums)
```